# Docker on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Went to launch an `Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09.1 (HVM) - ami-6e7bd919` earlier, claiming that:

It includes the 3.14 kernel, Ruby 2.1, PHP 5.5, PostgreSQL 9.3, **Docker 1.2**, the AWS command line tools, and repository access to many other packages.

First thing I do when I login:

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-45-67-89 ~]$ docker
-bash: docker: command not found
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be 100% precise : Amazon Linux ships with Docker's kernel extensions built-in but the docker CLI needs to be installed from the repository, as explained in other answers

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command to confirm

```
$ yum list installed |grep docker
```

So you didn't find the pakcage `docker` to be installed.

But if you list it, it's there. It is ready for you to install it.

```
$ yum list |grep docker

docker.x86_64                       1.3.3-1.0.amzn1                 amzn-updates
docker-devel.x86_64                 1.3.3-1.0.amzn1                 amzn-updates
docker-pkg-devel.x86_64             1.3.3-1.0.amzn1                 amzn-updates
```

Then you can run `yum install docker` to install it.

```
# yum install docker
...
# which docker
/usr/bin/docker
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try these steps. I think the most easiest way to make it done.

```
-sudo yum update

-sudo yum install -y docker

-sudo service docker start
```

Check if docker is running by `docker -v` and it will return

```
Docker version 1.3.1, build c78088f/1.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try yum install docker. Docker is in the repo but not pre installed.